# Can a single BLE module be connected to a mesh and have a point-to-point connection?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, embedded-linux, p2p, mesh-network

I want to know if it's possible to use a BLE module for both mesh networking and point-to-point connections at the same time.

#### Rationale:

The embedded linux (EL) product that I am designing needs to be able to connect to BLE peripherals like a heart rate monitor (sports grade, not medical) and the product needs to communicate with others of its kind.

I also need a very low power way of sending data from all EL devices to the internet. Ideally with only one of the products supplying a connection to the internet.

I am open to other solutions or reasons why this might not be a good approach even if it's possible.

Here is a rough block diagram of what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: block diagram]
The block diagram does not show a HR connected to every EL device, however this would be a possibility as well.

```
Green = Embedded Linux Devices
Red = Heart Rate Monitors
Blue = An internet connection to the cloud
Yellow = connections between Embedded Devices
```

#### Option 1 - WiFi

The first option I considered was a wifi connection between the EL devices, however this will consume much more power than BLE.

#### Option 2 - BLE mesh

Using a BLE mesh seems like the best solution, if and only if, it's possible to do point-to-point connection at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this behaviour is specified in the [BLE Mesh Profile](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/mesh-profile-1-0-1/) specification in chapter 2.3.11. What you are looking for is a Proxy Node:

> Proxy feature – the ability to receive and retransmit mesh messages between GATT and
> advertising bearers.

Also take a look at the [Ultimate Mesh Tutorial](https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-mesh-tutorial-part-2/#:%7E:text=1%3A%20Relay%20node-,Proxy%20Nodes,-To%20allow%20communication) where they also describe the proxy node:

> To allow communication with a mesh network from a non-mesh-supported BLE device, a special type of node called a proxy node can be utilized. A proxy node acts as an intermediary and utilizes GATT operations to allow other nodes outside of the mesh network to interface and interact with the network.
>
> The protocol used in this case is called the proxy protocol, which is intended to be used with a connection-enabled device (using GATT).

This is of course hardware and software dependent. Not every hardware or software stack supports BLE mesh functionality.

The wikipedia article for [Bluetooth mesh networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_mesh_networking#Implementations) has a list of currently availible software stack supporting BLE mesh.

Comment: Thank you for your response.


I saw the proxy feature, but my understanding of it is that it allows something like a smartphone to act as an end node in the mesh network.


I want to communicate with something that is not part of the mesh network, it's just a point-to-point connection with a BLE peripheral.

For example: would you connect an Apple Watch or Garmin watch to the mesh network?

Comment: To communicate with something outside of your mesh you need a proxy node. It is part of the network and can also communicate with devices that are not part of it. I would suggest that all of your devices implement the proxy feature and would therefore be part of the network and also capable of communicating with a outside device

Comment: `"It is part of the network and can also communicate with devices that are not part of it."` That seems like the right idea but I have been unable to find any resources on how to actually do that. All the resources I've found seem to suggest that the non-mesh-supported BLE device must join the network as an end node (and that this requires an application on the non-mesh-supported BLE device to work). I would definitely make all the embedded devices proxy nodes.

Comment: This might absolutely depend on the hardware/software you are using. We use a nRF52480 for our project and [this example](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.nordic.infocenter.meshsdk.v5.0.0%2Fmd_examples_README.html) shows how to integrate BLE mesh functionality into an existing BLEproject with UART functionality. There is also [this](https://github.com/NordicPlayground/nrf52-mesh-light-switch-client-server-proxy) repository showing multiple parts of a mesh network including a proxy

Comment: I still need to select hardware/software for this project. It looks like the best option is going to be using WiFi after all.

Thank you for your help.